# Java equivalent for php AES encryption

Tags: java, php, aes

**Help me on Java equivalent of PHP AES Encryption**.

I tried with java AES encryption it was working but the below equivalent php code not giving correct encryption decryption with java

I have given php and equivalent java code, but result is not expected one.
PHP code:

```
function encrypt($plainText)
{
    $key='12345678912345671234567891234567';    //size 32
    $md5=md5($key);
    $plainText='I am plain text';
    $secretKey = hextobin($md5);

    $initVector = pack("C*", 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f);
    $openMode = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '','cbc', '');
    $blockSize = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 'cbc');
    $plainPad = pkcs5_pad($plainText, $blockSize);
    if (mcrypt_generic_init($openMode, $secretKey, $initVector) != -1) 
    {
          $encryptedText = mcrypt_generic($openMode, $plainPad);
          mcrypt_generic_deinit($openMode);
    } 
    $data = bin2hex($encryptedText); 

    return $data;
}

function decrypt($encryptedText)
{
    $key='12345678912345671234567891234567';    
    $md5=md5($key);
    $secretKey = hextobin($md5);


    $initVector = pack("C*", 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f);
    $encryptedText=hextobin($encryptedText);
    $openMode = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '','cbc', '');
    mcrypt_generic_init($openMode, $secretKey, $initVector);
    $decryptedText = mdecrypt_generic($openMode, $encryptedText);
    $decryptedText = rtrim($decryptedText, "\0");
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($openMode);
    return $decryptedText;

}
//*********** Padding Function *********************

 function pkcs5_pad ($plainText, $blockSize)
{
    $pad = $blockSize - (strlen($plainText) % $blockSize);
    return $plainText . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}

//********** Hexadecimal to Binary function for php 4.0 version ********

function hextobin($hexString) 
 { 
        $length = strlen($hexString); 
        $binString="";   
        $count=0; 
        while($count<$length) 
        {       
            $subString =substr($hexString,$count,2);           
            $packedString = pack("H*",$subString); 
            if ($count==0)
        {
            $binString=$packedString;
        } 

        else 
        {
            $binString.=$packedString;
        } 

        $count+=2; 
        } 
        return $binString; 
      }
```

Java code:

```
public class StatusAES2 {

private static final String key = "12345678912345671234567891234567";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String plainText = "I am plain text";
    System.out.println("Original String to encrypt - " + plainText);
    String encryptedString = encrypt(plainText);
    System.out.println("Encrypted String - " + encryptedString);
    String decryptedString = decrypt(encryptedString);
    System.out.println("After decryption - " + decryptedString);

}

public static String encrypt(String value) {
    try {
        byte[] keybytes=key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] thedigest = md.digest(keybytes);
        String md5Str=Hex.encodeHexString(thedigest);

        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15});
        keybytes=hextobin(md5Str).getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keybytes, "AES");


        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
        String encryptedText=Hex.encodeHexString(encrypted);//bin2hex
        return encryptedText;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static String decrypt(String encrypted) {
    try {

        byte[] keybytes=key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] thedigest = md.digest(keybytes);
        String md5Str=Hex.encodeHexString(thedigest);

        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15});
        keybytes=hextobin(md5Str).getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keybytes, "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Hex.decodeHex(encrypted.toCharArray()));
        return new String(original);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public static String hextobin(String s) throws DecoderException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    int length=s.length();
    int count=0;
    String binString="";
    while(count<length){
        int c=count+2;
        String subs=s.substring(count,c);

        String packedString="";
        byte[] somevar = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(subs);
        byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(subs.toCharArray());
        packedString=new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
        if (count==0){
            binString=packedString;
        }else {
            binString=binString+packedString;
        } 
        count=count+2; 

    }
  return binString;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
            <version>1.46</version>
        </dependency>
```

Try this

```
CBCBlockCipher cbcBlockCipher = new CBCBlockCipher(new AESEngine());

        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

        KeyParameter key = new KeyParameter(yourSecretKey);

        BlockCipherPadding blockCipherPadding = new PKCS7Padding();
    PaddedBufferedBlockCipher pbbc = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(cbcBlockCipher, blockCipherPadding);
private byte[] processing(byte[] input, boolean encrypt) throws DataLengthException, InvalidCipherTextException {

        int blockSize = cbcBlockCipher.getBlockSize();
        int inputOffset = 0;
        int inputLength = input.length;
        int outputOffset = 0;

        byte[] initializationVector = new byte[blockSize];
        if (encrypt) {
            random.nextBytes(initializationVector);
            outputOffset += blockSize;
        } else {
            System.arraycopy(input, 0, initializationVector, 0, blockSize);
            inputOffset += blockSize;
            inputLength -= blockSize;
        }

        pbbc.init(encrypt, new ParametersWithIV(key, initializationVector));
        byte[] output = new byte[pbbc.getOutputSize(inputLength) + outputOffset];

        if (encrypt) {
            System.arraycopy(initializationVector, 0, output, 0, blockSize);
        }

        int outputLength = outputOffset + pbbc.processBytes(input, inputOffset, inputLength, output, outputOffset);

        outputLength += pbbc.doFinal(output, outputLength);

        return Arrays.copyOf(output, outputLength);

    }
```